# In ArcMap, how to highlight the overlapping part when it is superimposed in the same layer？

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, symbology, mapping

In ArcMap, I want to know how to make this effect without splitting the data in the same layer?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In ArcGIS, you can do that by assigning transparent value in a field in the attribute table.

In [Setting layer transparency](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/how-to-set-layer-transparency.htm) under Tip, it says:

> - **For layers using a single symbol or for layers displayed by category,    you can set the transparency of individual features using
>     field    values to set percent transparency.**
> - You can set transparency for group layers. In these cases, it will    take into account the transparency settings of each sublayer in the
>     overall group layer transparency.
> - Layer transparency is applied to all features in the layer with each    transparent object knocking out previously drawn transparent
>     features    in the same layer. Therefore, transparent features in the
>     same layer    will not blend with each other.

Practically, add a field with integer type and give it a name (opacity in the example):

[image]

Then go to `Layer Properties -> Symbology -> Advanced -> Transparent` and select the Opacity field.

[image]

[image]

Apply. Here is the output

[image]

**Option 2:**

If you have the chance to use open source QGIS, it is much easier. All you need to do is to change the feature's blending mode to `Multiply`. No need to create a new field.

[image]

Comment: Real question with ArcGIS solution is how to define these subgroups isn't it?

Comment: @FelixIP Yes it is correct. As far as I know, ArcGIS does not support blending mode for features in the same layer but it can be done with transparent option, although it is not as clear as the one in QGIS. This is why I provided a QGIS solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can count number of times each polygon intersects others. Transfer count into original layer and as suggested by @ahmadhanb apply different transparency to subgroups:

[image]

In case shown above count range was 0..16, so I use

```
10+ [FREQUENCY]*5
```

to populate transparency field by numbers in range 10...90.
Doesn't work on a group containing same number of intersections...